# PHP switch case, 0 is not getting recognized as a value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a switch case statement in a PHP script that returns a string value based on the 'Day' and 'Hour' value supplied by a Ajax call from a JS file.But whenever the values are 0(i.e, Sunday for the day variable and 0 as in midnight for the hour variable) the statement doesn't work and the value returns empty.I can't seem to find a solution here is a shorter version of the code for the PHP function and the Ajax Call;

```
function getDayTimeData($day, $time){
    $program = "";
    switch($day){
        case 0: //Sunday
            switch($time){
                case $time < 1:
                    $program = 'Be Our Guest';
                    break;
                case $time < 6:
                    $program = 'Club Technoise';
                    break;
                case $time < 12:
                    $program = 'Morning Juice';
                    break;
                case $time < 21:
                    $program = 'Detox';
                    break;
                case $time < 24:
                    $program = 'Disco Ball';
                    break;
            }
            break;
     }
}
if(isset($_POST["DayData"]) && isset($_POST["TimeData"]))
{
    echo(getDayTimeData($_POST["DayData"],$_POST["TimeData"]));
}
```

Here's is the Jquery Ajax Script

```
function getDayTimeAjax(_day,_time){
    var def2 = $.Deferred();
    
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(xhr && xhr.readyState != 4){
            xhr.abort();
        }
        var xhr = $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'returnPoster.php',
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            data: {DayData: _day, TimeData: _time},
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(x){
                programInfo = x;
                def2.resolve();
            }
        })
    },2000);
    return $.when(def2).done(function(){}).promise();
}

var d = new Date();
var programInfo = ".";

setInterval(function () { updateProgram() }, 3000);

function updateProgram(){
    getDayTimeAjax(d.getDay(),d.getHours()).done(function(){
        console.log(programInfo.trim());
    })
}
```

**EDIT:** Sorry guys looks like I have given some misinformation on the subject as I was in kind of a hurry when I set this thread up.**The problem only occurs when the $time value is 0**.The values seem fine up until "case $time <1:" operation occurs.From there on even though the $time variable has a value of 0, It doesn't execute the code block inside the first case, so the program variable stays empty.All other values returned the values from the switch statement.

Comment: Where do you return the `$program` variable in `getTimeData` ?

Comment: "Doesn't work" sounds pretty broad. What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: I have the edited the thread to correspond to your questions.Sorry about the missing informantion.

Comment: @Al.G. I echo the value if the post values are set on the page so that javascript can read that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies with the switch statement, if you take this:

```
    switch($time){
        case $time < 1:
        ...
    }
```

And fill in a value for $time, like 0:

```
    switch(0){
        case 0 < 1:
        ...
    }
```

Then compare the value in the `switch()` call to the value after `case`:

```
0 == true
```

Well, this—and all other comparisons—are `false`. If you really want to use a comparison using less-than in your switch statement, you'd need to do this:

```
    switch(true){
        case $time < 1:
        ...
    }
```

Then the comparison would be:

```
true == true
```

Note that in your original code, when the value for `$time` is not 0, it'd compare for example `3 == true` which, because `switch` does not check strictly (it uses ==, not ===), is `true`. It would *always* return the first result 'Be our guest', no matter the value.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this really solved my problem.I didn't think the comparisons would make that much trouble.

Answer (score 2):

### You cannot compare integer value and time like this,

```
switch($time){
    case $time < 1:
      break;
}
```

*try to compare same type values.*

Comment: The value types are same they are both integers values in that point.The JS methods getHours() and getDay() return integer values between 0-23 and 0-6 respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small example. This will echo a program based on time. To identify day I recommend to use IF instead of switch case.

```
$time = date("H");
$day = date("w");
$program = "";

if($day == 0){
  switch($time){
    case $time < 1:
      $program = 'Be Our Guest';
      break;
    case $time < 6:
      $program = 'Club Technoise';
      break;
    case $time < 12:
      $program = 'Morning Juice';
      break;
    case $time < 21:
      $program = 'Detox';
      break;
    case $time < 24:
      $program = 'Disco Ball';
      break;
    }
  }else{
     .......
  }
echo $program;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this, it may work with the first switch also, but i prefer to use **if** instead:

```
function getDayTimeData ($day, $time)
{
    if ((int) $day === 0) {
        switch($time){
            case $time < 1:
                $program = 'Be Our Guest';
            break;
            case $time < 6:
                $program = 'Club Technoise';
            break;
            case $time < 12:
                $program = 'Morning Juice';
            break;
            case $time < 21:
                $program = 'Detox';
            break;
            case $time < 24:
                $program = 'Disco Ball';
            break;
        }
    }
}

if(isset($_POST["DayData"]) && isset($_POST["TimeData"]))
{
    echo(getDayTimeData($_POST["DayData"],$_POST["TimeData"]));
}
```